# Getting all of the fields using SQL Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, multiple-tables

So Here is my problem. I have multiple tables that I need to pull data from.

### A Project table

Project id
project name
etc

### Project Needs table

need id
need

### Need to projects table

project id
need id

### volunteer table (aka members)

all the member data

### member_skills table

member_id
skill_id (aka need for projects)

here is my query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO PROJECT_NOTIFY_TEMP (project_id, project_name, volunteer_name, volunteer_email, volunteer_skills)
SELECT p.project_id as PROJECT_ID, p.project_name as PROJECT_NAME, CONCAT(m.first_name,' ',m.last_name) as FULL_NAME, m.email as EMAIL, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pn.need ORDER BY pn.need SEPARATOR ', ') as NEED
FROM PROJECTS p
JOIN project_needs_to_projects pntp
ON (pntp.project_id = p.PROJECT_ID)
JOIN project_needs pn
ON (pntp.need_id = pn.need_id AND pn.active = 'Y')
JOIN member_skills ms
ON (pn.need_id = ms.skill_id)
JOIN members m
ON (ms.member_id = m.member_id)
WHERE p.PROJECT_ID = '".$PROJECT_ID."' 
GROUP BY m.member_id";
```

It pulls all of the information correctly, but I have been unable to figure out how to pull all of the project needs. Right now it only pulls the needs that I have a volunteer match for.
Basically, I want to pull those (as skills) and pull the project needs (as needs)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without some sample data and expected output.

This can happen if all values of `project_needs` are not in `project_needs_to_projects` table. As you are using `JOIN`, it trys to return records with matching values in both tables on left and right side of the `JOIN`.

Using `RIGHT JOIN` for `project_needs` instead of `JOIN` will return all values from `project_needs` and matching values + null values from `project_needs_to_projects` table. You query will look like

```
SELECT p.project_id as PROJECT_ID, p.project_name as PROJECT_NAME,
CONCAT(m.first_name,' ',m.last_name) as FULL_NAME, m.email as EMAIL,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pn.need ORDER BY pn.need SEPARATOR ', ') as NEED
FROM PROJECTS p
    JOIN project_needs_to_projects pntp
    ON (pntp.project_id = p.PROJECT_ID)
    RIGHT JOIN project_needs pn
    ON (pntp.need_id = pn.need_id AND pn.active = 'Y')...
```